# jQuery scroll and animate element on path

Tags: jquery, svg, scroll, path

I'm trying to get two things done: show an element (in my case: simple red box) along a svg path while scrolling. The scrolling is done, and it was quite easy with the [jquery-drawsvg plugin](https://github.com/lcdsantos/jquery-drawsvg).

But showing an element on the path is the challenge.

To get a picture of what I'm trying: http://yaireo.github.io/pathAnimator/

In the example, the animation starts and ends automatically, but I want to move the arrow (the animation) whenever a user scrolls. How can I relate the coordinates of an element to a svg path?

PS: I would love to post my code, but it really is a mix (mess) of both plugins - and not working at all. That's why I have asked the question above.

Comment: I'm not sure the example if working properly. There is just a small red box in the top left corner and nothing happens as I scroll, just a typical scroll, the page contents move up...

Comment: I'm sorry! I have edited my main post. The first idea works, which is scrolling and drawing the path of the svg. The next step is to combine it with a small red box which follows the path - and that's something I haven't been able to do.

Answer (score 2):

Although I still have no clue how to make this work on my own, I found a plugin called [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). It lets you stick an element on a svg path while scrolling: see [this](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr-path/) example. Bless whoever made and contributed to this.